# Using awk array in regular expression

Tags: awk

I am trying to search a pattern stored in awk array "a" read from file1 and then search in 4rth column of file2 , the following command works perfectly

```
awk -F" " 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}{for (i in a){ if($4 ~ a[i])print $0}}'  file1 file2
```

but If I change the command at `if`  to search at the start of 4rth column of file2 as shown below  , it does not work , any suggestions please ?

```
awk -F" " 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}{for (i in a){ if($4 ~ "^a[i]" )print $0}}'  file1 file2
```

can the second command be modified to search the array element at the start of 4rth column in file2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `"^a[i]"` to `"^"a[i]`......

Comment: My goodness!! , Thanks ED, I realised that I can also combine regular expressions just like "^"a[i]".*"